# IP Address for a socket address

Tags: sockets, ip

So I know that a socket address is the combination of an IP address and a port number, but which IP address is used for the socket address? Is it the private or the public IP address, or can it be both but you have to choose one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A connected socket can have any IP which is local on the machine - but only one at a time. A socket which is not connected (i.e. listening socket in case of TCP) can instead also be bound the catch-all IP (`0.0.0.0` for IPv4, `::` for IPv6) and thus receive data on all local IP.

Comment: So, I'm assuming that a local IP is the same as a private IP?

Comment: @MichaelB: A local IP address is an IP address which is configured on a local real or virtual network interface on the machine. This can be an IP only accessible on the local machine (like 127.0.0.1), a private IP accessible only from the LAN but also a public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Running `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` will give you the IP address it is using.

Comment: I assume your code fragment should be Python. But it is still wrong. The correct way would be to call `getsockname` on the socket.

Comment: But I don't get whats wrong with it. It does return the current IP address and I don't reckon socket's gonna use some other IP address unless we force it to

Comment: The local IP address used depends on the destination of a connected socket. Is the destination localhost than 127.0.0.1 (or ::1) will be used. If the destination is non-local then IP of the machine inside the LAN will be used. Modern systems usually have IPv4 and IPv6 so which of these gets used depends on the protocol of the socket. Maschines can have even more IP, like the IP of the VPN tunnel, multiple public IP, IP for virtual machines on the system ... . Your code returns exactly one of these many possible IP.

Comment: For example on my machine your code returns just 127.0.1.1 - which is definitely not the local IP used for most sockets on this machine.